# Mesos setup slave deactivated

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere

I am trying to set up a **mesos** cluster on ubuntu. Not using **zookeeper** since i need only single master cluster. I started the master and then tried to start slave on another machine by running following command:

```
mesos-slave.sh --master=master-ip:5050
```

On the Mesos Web UI the slave is listed as `Deactivated`. if i try to start a slave on the same machine as master then the slave starts and is listed as `Activated`.

Is there some configuration i am missing here to be able to start slaves?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. We need to also specify the ip of the slave so that the master can communicate with it.

```
mesos-slave.sh --master=master-ip:5050 --ip=<ip_of_slave_machine>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see the next lines on mesos-master logs it means you **forget** to mention mesos-agent "--ip" parameter when starting mesos-agent!

```
master.cpp:5639] Registered agent AGENT_ID... at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (AGENT-HOSTNAME) with ....
master.cpp:1313] Agent AGENT_ID at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (AGENT-HOSTNAME) disconnected
master.cpp:3197] Disconnecting agent AGENT_ID at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (AGENT-HOSTNAME)
master.cpp:3216] Deactivating agent AGENT_ID at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (AGENT-HOSTNAME)
process.cpp:2450] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 16, address 127.0.0.1:36622: Transport endpoint is not connected
```